# AngularJS : Bootstrap typeahead with multiselect

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-typeahead, bootstrap-multiselect

I am using bootstrap multiselect in my angular application. (Bootstrap 2.3)

http://davidstutz.github.io/bootstrap-multiselect/index-2-3.html#examples

[image]

I want to convert the same thing in to bootstrap typeahead but still the user can multiselect values in search results.

[image]

I am using the highlighter function of bootstrap typeahed to add check-boxes to results.
I am referring to the this plnkr http://plnkr.co/edit/szO2An1oslDyGftnshyR?p=preview but I am still unable to make my code work.

Old Code for multiselect:

1. to check last selected values

   ```
   $scope.selectOptions = function () {
   var index = fetching the index of checked values;
   var selectedAttrFound = index>-1;
   if (selectedAttrFound == true) {
   angular.element("#attr-value-selector")
   .multiselect('select', $scope.filterAttributes[index].attributeValues);
   }
   };
   ```
2. to populate the multiselect

   ```
   $scope.attrValuesWidget = angular.element("#attr-value-selector")
   .multiselect({
    numberDisplayed: 2,
    enableFiltering: true,
    maxHeight: "300",
    onChange: function (element, checked) {
    $scope.attributeActionValue = {
    attribute: $scope.attributeSelected,
    value: element.val(),
    checked: checked
    };
    $scope.$apply();
    }
    })
    .multiselect('dataprovider', $scope.configAttributeValuesList);
   ```
3. The Select box

   ```
   <select id='attr-value-selector' multiple='multiple' ></select>
   ```

Answer (score 2):

Although you can easily add checkboxes in your highlighter function..

```
highlighter: function( item ){
    var bond = bondObjs[ item ];              
    return '<div class="bond">'
            +'<input type="checkbox" class="mightBeRequiredToCollectTheSelectedResult">' 
            +'<img src="' + bond.photo + '" />'
            +'<br/><strong>' + bond.name + '</strong>'
            +'</div>';
}
```

The problems are;

- typehead.js automatically closes its result after you click one of
  the search result. You need to override this first.
- Then you also need to list the selected values into the textfield.

If you check typehead.js github issues page, issue #254 mentioned that they don't have plan to support multi select, at least for now.

Now I might get downvoted for this, but If I were you I'll consider other alternatives as well.

- https://github.com/isteven/angular-multi-select: pure AngularJS, ability to rest selection.
- http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/: rich configuration options
- Or the old reliable "chosen" library (I can't post more links)

Hope it helps. Cheers.